# Using same parameter on a function, on multiple class arguments

Tags: php, laravel, oop

So basically I have this function

```
    public function deleteHolidaySupport($type,HolidaySupport $holidaySupport, Holiday $holiday)
{
    
    if ($type=='holidaySupport') {
        $this->holidaySupportRepository->delete($holidaySupport);
    }
    else {
        $this->holidayRepository->delete($holiday);
    }
    return response(['message' => __('server_response.messages.success')], 200);
}
```

Thing is that im only passing 2 parameters to this function, and thats how I want to do it. By passing only 2 parameters.

But the question is, how can i use the second parameter received from url, on the third argument as well? Because I need it for the `Holiday` class as well

Is there a way? I hope you get what I'm trying to do

Comment: Can you clarify your intention? It seems that you want to pass two parameters, but you want to pass three parameters.

Comment: yes,but third parameter would be the same as second parameter

Comment: So actually the second and the third parameter are identical? Or how do they differ?

Comment: Second and third parameter both have difference classes , as u can see

Comment: @john555 based on your last comment, your goal cannot be achieved as you'll get a type mismatch exception because `HolidaySupport` and `Holiday` are two different classes (types).

Answer (score 1):

PHP *allows* you to specify [Type Declared Variable Arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) but this isn't *required*. Instead you could use the [instanceof](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php)  operator to verify the class inside the function.

With this method you don't even need the first `$type` parameter.

```
public function deleteHolidayObject($obj) {
  if ($obj instanceof HolidaySupport) {
    $this->holidaySupportRepository->delete($obj);
  }
  
  elseif ($obj instanceof Holiday) {
    $this->holidayRepository->delete($obj);
  }
  
  else {
    // return bad request (HTTP 400)
  }
  
  return response(['message' => __('server_response.messages.success')], 200);
}
```